# Laravel, undefined variable ignacio class laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Hola el problema es que al pinchar *ignacio* este se redirecciona a *ignacio&20&&* y no solo *ignacio*.

**Ruta:**

```
Route::get('fotos/{nombre?}','App\Http\Controllers\pagescontrollers@personas')->name('nombre');//);
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function personas($nombre=null){
        $equipo=['ignacio','juanito']; //return view('fotos',['equipo'=>$equipo],'nombre'=>$nombre); return
    view('fotos',compact('equipo','nombre'));  //('equip' , 'variable')
         } }
```

**Plantilla:**

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->


<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document </title> </head> <body>

     <h1>bvbvvbbvbvbvbv</h1> <div>cabecera</div> <div class="container">   @yield('seccion')  </div> <div> fotter</div>
</body> </html>
```

**Archivo:**

```
@extends('plantilla') @section('seccion') <h1> fotos </h1> //<a
href="{{route('nosotros',$equipo}} class="h4 text-danger">{{$equipo}}
</a> @foreach($equipo as e) //$this->item = $item->$item; <a
href="{{route('nombre',$e)}} class="h4 text-danger">{{$e}}
</a> @endforeach

@if(!empty($nombre))
@switch($nombre)

@case('ignacio') <h2> el nombre es {{$nombre}} : </h2>
@break

@case('juanito') <h2> el nombre es {{$nombre}} : </h2>
@break @endswitch @endif @endsection

// problema es undefined offset 1
```

Comment: Route::get('fotos/{nombre?}','App\Http\Controllers\pagescontrollers@personas')->name('nombre');

Comment: Todo codigo va como texto, edita y agregalo

Comment: Tienes `$item->$item`, quitale el signo de dolar al ultimo, deberia ser asi `$item->item`, ademas el nombre como lo estas mandando debe ser al momento de usarlo en el blade.

Comment: listo ahorab sale "$item is undefined"

Comment: Listo cambie la var por equipo pero ahora sale undefined offset,: 1

Comment: Es algo en el foreeach el arregloocupar print r junto al arreglo

Comment: Error ignacio no esta definida class. Colocar @php ($nombre=' ')