# ¿Cómo declarar un array de tipo string Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un *array* de tipo *string* recibiendo 2 parámetros. El error sea el más obvio. No estoy declarándola.

**Archivo:**

```php
    $this->item = $item->item;
    @foreach($personas as $item)
        $this->item = $item->item;
        <a href="{{route('nombre',$item)}} class="h4 text-danger">{{$item}} </a>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Declaro una de estas variables, pero no funcionan. Error `$item is undefined`

Comment: Tu `Archivo` es la vista? Si es asi porque haces un `$this->item = $item->item;` Pon el codigo completo. Por otra parte el contenido de la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con el titulo que pusistes. Te recomiendo leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Entonces ya tengo una pregunta dedicada a ello

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432093/laravel-variable-indefinida-1?noredirect=1#comment771538_432093

Comment: Estoy pegadisimo